# Why wheredate not working in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My laravel eloquent is like this :

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = '';
    $searchdate = '2017-04-27';

    $reports = Report::whereHas('user', function($query) use ($search) 
    {
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search)
        {
            $q->where('name' ,'LIKE' ,'%'.$search.'%');
        });
    })->orWhereHas('store', function($query) use ($search){
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search)
        {
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
        });
    })->orWhereHas('category', function($query) use ($search)
    {
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search)
        {
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%');
        });
    })->whereDate('created_at','=',$searchdate)->paginate(10);
}
```

When executed, the result is not match with the filter `$searchdate`

How can I solve it?

**Update** :

I debug the query, the result is like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reports` WHERE (
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `reports`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `reports`.`reportable_id` = `stores`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `stores`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `reports`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `categories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
    AND DATE(`created_at`) = '2017-04-27'
) 
AND `reports`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Seems it does not work. Because

> AND DATE(`created_at`) = '2017-04-27'

are inside the round brackets

So, it must change like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `reports` WHERE (
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `reports`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `reports`.`reportable_id` = `stores`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `stores`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `reports`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` AND (`name` LIKE '%%') AND `categories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) 
) 
AND DATE(`created_at`) = '2017-04-27'
AND `reports`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

Which is my problem is how to change in eloquent laravel?

Comment: Is there no one can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the query to

```
$reports = Report::where(function($q) use ($search){
   $q->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($search) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search){
            $q->where('name' ,'LIKE' ,'%'.$search.'%');
        });
     })->orWhereHas('store', function($query) use ($search){
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search){
            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
        });
     })->orWhereHas('category', function($query) use ($search){
        $query->where(function ($q) use($search){
             $q->where('name', 'LIKE' , '%'.$search.'%');
     });
  });
})->whereDate('created_at','=',$searchdate)->paginate(10);
```

Hope it helps